# When do I have to use rectifier-inverter, and when is "dimmer circuit" sufficient in driving AC motor?

Tags: motor, ac, control

I'm trying to design a device that is to use a variable speed 1-phase AC motor. I still haven't decided upon power and other parameters of the motor. I have a few models to choose from, with "bigger is better" metric, but complexity of the device is a significant factor, so I'd prefer to avoid the need to use an amplifier-rectifier circuit.

Is there some rule-of-thumb or guide, how far can one go using a circuit with a triac chopping pieces of phase off the AC supply voltage, and when that solution is inadequate and I need a variable-frequency rectifier instead?

Answer (score 2):

A Triac 'dimmer circuit' chops the front end off each half cycle and so lowers the effective voltage to the induction motor, causing it to slip more and run at a lower speed. The main disadvantage of this method is high harmonic content, which causes excess heating in the motor.

If mechanical loading is strongly dependent on speed (eg. ceiling fan, water pump) then the load is also dramatically reduced at low speed so motor heating may not be a problem. If high loading is expected at low speed then a VFD is more appropriate.

There is a third option which is better than a Triac dimmer but simpler than VFD -  Single Phase PWM. This still works by lowering the effective voltage and causing slip, but eliminates the higher harmonics that cause excessive heating. Here's an application note that explains the technique:-

[PWM Control of Single-Phase A.C. Induction Motor Using MC68HC908](http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/prod_summary.jsp?code=RDHC08ACIM)

Comment: Are such PWM controllers available commercially (i.e., packaged for consumers)?  I can't seem to find any, which seems odd.